# Sort dictionary by integers of dictionary keys

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary like so:

```
thedict={'1':'the','2':2,'3':'five','10':'orange'}
```

and I want to sort this dictionary by key. If I do the following:

```
for key,value in sorted(thedict.iteritems()):
     print key,value
```

I will obtain

```
1 the
10 orange
2 2
3 five
```

since the keys are strings and not integers. I want to sort them as if they are integers, so the entry "10,orange" comes last. I thought something like this would work:

```
for key,value in sorted(thedict.iteritems(),key=int(operator.itemgetter(0))):
    print key,value
```

but that generated this error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'operator.itemgetter'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: `itemgetter(0)` is actually a function that is passed one item at a time from `.iteritems()`: For example `itemgetter(0)('ab')` will return 'a'. But `int(itemgetter(0))('ab')
` makes no sense, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could do that easy enough with a lambda expression:

```
sorted(thedict.iteritems(), key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
# with Python3, use thedict.items() for an iterator
```

The problem is that you are handing a callable object to the `int()` builtin and trying to use the return value of the `int()` call as a callable for the key. You need to create a callable for the key argument.

The error you are getting basically tells you that you can't call `int()` with an operator.itemgetter (callable), you can only call it with a string or a number.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the times when people's inexplicable attraction to `itemgetter` can lead them astray.  Simply use a `lambda`:

```
>>> thedict={'1':'the','2':2,'3':'five','10':'orange'}
>>> sorted(thedict.iteritems(), key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
[('1', 'the'), ('2', 2), ('3', 'five'), ('10', 'orange')]
```

The problem is that `int(operator.itemgetter(0))` is being evaluated immediately, in order to pass it as an argument to `sorted`.  So you're building an `itemgetter`, and then trying to call `int` on it (which isn't working, because it's not a string or a number).

Comment: +1 was about to post the exact same solution but you beat me to it

Comment: Thanks DSM. Gavin's answer was essentially equivalent and perhaps beat you by a few seconds so I gave the answer to him.

Comment: @gammapoint: no worries!  In fact, even apart from his beating me to the punch, I think that if there are two essentially equivalent answers it's better on the whole to give the checkmark to the guy with the lower rep-- that helps move him toward getting new abilities on the site.